Isotopy of homeomorphism of $\mathbb{D}$ fixing the boundary and an inner point $z_0$
I want to prove the following
Let $\varphi:\mathbb{D} \rightarrow \mathbb{D}$ be an homeomorphism fixing the boundary with a fixed point $z_0$. Then there exists $0<r_0<r_1< 1 -|z_0|$ and an isotopy H fixing the boundary of $\mathbb{D}$ for all time and such that:

$H_0 = \varphi$
$H_t=   \varphi$ in $\mathbb{D} \setminus \mathring{\mathbb{D}}_{r_1}(z_0)$
$H_1= \mathbb{Id}$ in $\mathbb{D}_{r_0}(z_0)$.

To sum it up, it is an isotopy fixing the boundary and equal to $\varphi$ for any time in outside a disk of radius $r_1$, from $\varphi$ to an homeomorphism  that is the identity inside a disk centered al $z_0$ of radius $r_0$
I have already proven the following results:

An homeomorphism of $\mathbb{S}^1$ to itself is either isotopic to the identity or to the complex conjugation
The same as 1. but in $\mathbb{D}$
An homeomorphism of $\mathbb{D}$ to itself fixing the boundary (what I call a $\partial$-homeomorphism) is isotopic to the identity, with the isotopy fixing the boundary of $\mathbb{D}$ (what I call a $\partial$-isotopy)

To start I supose that $z_0 = 0$, to make things easier. Then I take a disk $\mathbb{D_{r_{1}}}$
and its image by $\varphi$ and then another $r_0 < r_1$ such that $\mathbb{D_{r_{0}}} \subseteq \varphi(\mathbb{D_{r_{1}}})$
I would like to prove that there is a homeomorphism $\phi$ from $\mathbb{D_{r_{1}}} \setminus \mathring{\mathbb{D_{r_{0}}}}$ to $\varphi(\mathbb{D_{r_{1}}}) \setminus \mathring{\mathbb{D_{r_{0}}}}$ verifying:

$\phi$ restricted to $\mathbb{S_{r_{1}}}$ $=$ $\varphi$ restricted to $\mathbb{S_{r_{1}}}$
$\phi$ restricted to $\mathbb{S_{r_{0}}}$ $=$ $\mathbb{Id}$ in $\mathbb{S_{r_{0}}}$

This way I could extend $\phi$ to the identity in $\mathring{\mathbb{D_{r_{0}}}}$ and  to $\varphi$ in $\mathbb{D} \setminus \mathbb{D_{r_{1}}}$.
I have only proven that there exists an homeomorphism $\phi$ that restricted to $\mathbb{S_{r_{0}}}$ $=$ $\mathbb{Id}$ in $\mathbb{S_{r_{0}}}$, but I cannot prove the first one.
If anyone reading this wants more datails, doesn´t understand something from the quesion (I probably haven`t explained some aspects very well), or wants to know how I proved what I know or wants a drawing, just say it in the comments.
Thanks!
